# Setting **kwargs like parameter in resolver function

Tags: python, graphene-python, strawberry-graphql, ariadne-graphql, graphql-python

I'm using Strawberry for GraphQL with FastAPI and SQLAlchemy. I have about 20 tables in MySQL. I'm using SQLAlchemy for models (inherit `DeclarativeBase`). For strawberry models I'm using `strawberry-sqlalchemy-mapper`. I could write a third layer of models as filters (`@strawberry.input`), but that doesn't sound good.

I've encountered the following problems:

- Can't use undetermined parameters in client-side queries without setting up each parameter at Strawberry resolver (server-side `Query`);
- Couldn't create universal Filter class (based on `@strawberry.input` -> [GPT Generated Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2krl.png)).

I need something similar to the code in the picture above so I can write GraphQL query with some parameters and get response without error. I want to retrieve a dictionary-like data of client request parameters and process it, instead of defining each parameter manually. I can work with `Info` object, however Strawberry still won't skip undefined parameters

I haven't looked at how Graphene or Ariadne works, is there a way to solve this problem there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in strawberry. It requires working with lower-level APIs, simulating what `strawberry.field` does with parameters. Here's a minimal example:

```py
import strawberry
from strawberry.annotation import StrawberryAnnotation
from strawberry.arguments import StrawberryArgument


# no @strawberry.type yet
class Query:
    @strawberry.field
    def dynamic(self, **kwargs: object) -> list[str]:
        return list(kwargs)


fields = {'x': int, 'y': str}  # from a dynamic schema
Query.dynamic.base_resolver.arguments = [
    StrawberryArgument(name, name, StrawberryAnnotation(fields[name])) for name in fields
]
schema = strawberry.Schema(strawberry.type(Query))
```

```bash
% strawberry export-schema ...
type Query {
  dynamic(x: Int!, y: String!): [String!]!
}
```